# Getting the previous "Head" after list traversal in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

The title may be off but I have a function called `log_norm/1`, It simply returns a list of log normalized values using the formula: *log(Input<sub>t</sub>/Input<sub>t-1</sub>)* (log of present Input over previous Input) applied to each element in the list.

```
log_norm(List) ->
    log_norm(List,[]).
log_norm([], Newlist) ->
    lists:reverse(Newlist);
log_norm([Input|T], Newlist) ->
    X = math:log(Input/???), % ??? should be the previous head of the list Input-1. 
    log_norm(T, [X|Newlist]).
```

How do I get the previous "head" or input after traversing to the new "head" of the list?

Comment: Read two values from the head of the list using log_norm([Input_prev|Input|T], Newlist) -> ...

Comment: also you can use lists:nth() for such purposes accessing the nth element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I think will work.

```
log_norm(List = [_H1,_H2|_T]) ->
    log_norm(List,[]);
log_norm(_) ->
    bad_argument.

log_norm([Input_prev,Input], Newlist) ->
    X = math:log(Input/Input_prev), 
    lists:reverse([X|Newlist]);
log_norm([Input_prev,Input|T], Newlist) ->
    X = math:log(Input/Input_prev), 
    log_norm([Input|T], [X|Newlist]).
```

Comment: it will never happen!the base case is with 2 elements, and you can't calculate with one element because you want the i-1.

Comment: If you test it you will see :D                                     2> language:log_norm([1,2]).
[0.6931471805599453]
3> language:log_norm([1]).
bad_argument
4> language:log_norm([1,2,3]).
[0.6931471805599453,0.4054651081081644]

Comment: I've added another answer using the lists:nth() that you recommended, and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

I've also created a solution by adding 2 arguments, the original list and a counter N to be used for getting the previous using lists:nth() :D

```
 log_norm(List) ->
        log_norm(List,[], List, 0).
    log_norm([], Newlist, _,_) ->
        lists:reverse(Newlist);
    log_norm([Input|T], Newlist, OrigList, N) ->
        if
            N == 0 -> X = math:log(Input/Input);
            true -> X = math:log(Input/lists:nth(N, OrigList))
        end,
        log_norm(T, [X|Newlist], OrigList, N+1).
```

Comment: yep this works as well, I don't think you will have this problem in this question but remember in general carrying around a duplicate of the list is not efficient. again I don't think it matters for this question ;)

Comment: @Khashayar Carrying around an extra "copy" in an another argument costs very little as the list is not copied, it is just a referenced which is passed around. Doing a lists:nth costs much more. It is much faster to match off two elements at a time.

Comment: @rvirding you are absolutely right! Thats what I did in my answer as well. Hope to see you in Goteborg :D

Answer (score -1):

use hd().

```
log_norm(List) ->
    log_norm(List,[]).
log_norm([Input,Last], Newlist) ->
    X =math:log(Input/Last),
    lists:reverse([X|Newlist]);
log_norm([Input|T], Newlist) ->
    X = math:log(Input/hd(T)), 
    log_norm(T, [X|Newlist]).
```

Comment: This will fail in case of List having only one element!